# '90s/early 2000s sci-fi TV show featuring a cone-headed alien/robot-like thing and a triangular/pyramid-shaped UFO

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv, ufos

I can barely remember anything about it, except that the intro had some epic, spooky guitar riffs. The show follows a crowd of young people and is set on present-day Earth, IIRC.

I remember this one thing that's been plaguing my memories; used to freak me out as a kid.
Towards the end of the opening and in the show, a cone-headed alien/robot-like thingy appears on a hill, and that one shot has a green scanline filter on it; a bit *Matrix*-like.
It's hard to explain, but I did a rough sketch of what that thing looked like:

[image]

I believe the show was British, but I might be wrong. At some point, a triangular/pyramid-shaped UFO appears. That's it.
Any sort of info would be appreciated; if anyone can recall the name or knows which show it is.

Comment: Has a bit in common with Aquila (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5b2J_PX-ArA) but I can't find that robot, and the spacecraft's in it a lot more than your question seems to imply. There's also Mike and Angelo , which briefly had a pyramid spacecraft in the opening - maybe the conehead robot was just in one episode? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElDuwcm2nGk for that.

Comment: The crowd of young people (and it possibly being 90s) made me think of The Tomorrow People.  There was an Egyptian themed story, but I didn't see anything resembling what you described in the intro:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PNrVFv4a9A&list=PL8vAvnjHeJNtA1zwSGVzv13XxBrdfefBL&index=16